# Adding new key-value pair in an existing json element

Tags: json, perl, hashmap

I am having a perl script which is basically generating JSON from an XML. This part is working fine. But after doing some business logic i need to add a new key-value pair to an existing element in the JSON.

I am able to insert a completely new element in JSON but not a key-value pair in an existing element of input JSON.

Here is sample JSON:

```
{
    "Person": {
       "ID": "0", 
       "SchemaVersion": "1.0.8", 
       "Home": {
          "ID": "ABC-XYZ", 

          "Laptop": {
             "FileName": "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz"
           }, 

          "Location": {
              "Number": "62", 
              "MaxSize": "0", 
              "Comment": { }, 
              "SiteName": { }
           }, 

          "State": "Unknown"
       }
    }
 }
```

Now in above json i am trying to add a new key-value pair generated based on some business logic under element Laptop ( Person->Home->Laptop ). 
( key-value pair example :  "Key":"123456789" ), so new JSON looks like this :

```
{
    "Person": {
       "ID": "0", 
       "SchemaVersion": "1.0.8", 
       "Home": {
          "ID": "ABC-XYZ", 

          "Laptop": {
             "FileName": "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz",
             "Key": "123456789"
           }, 

          "Location": {
              "Number": "62", 
              "MaxSize": "0", 
              "Comment": { }, 
              "SiteName": { }
           }, 

          "State": "Unknown"
       }
    }
 }
```

What approach i have taken in perl code is :

1. Converting the JSON first to a hash map
2. Trying to add the new element ( this is where problem is occuring, i am able to add a completely new element but not add a key-value pair inside an existing element )
3. Convert the hash map back to JSON.

Perl code for the same:  ( ignore any missing use statements, making script less complicated just to highlight the error )

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings FATAL => qw( all );
 use Data::Dumper;

 use JSON;

# get back the original JSON into a hashmap (key value pairs)
 ( $json is output of JSON generated from an XML file but for this example 
   please use the sample JSON i have mentioned above )
my $tempHash = decode_json($json);  

# new key-value pair that needs to be added in the JSON ( in original code   
  it is being generated from business logic but in similar format )
 %filedata = ('Key', 123456789);

# insert the fileKey now. Think about how to insert the file key here
push @{ $tempHash->{'Person'}->{'Home'}->{'Laptop'}}, $\%fileData; 

my $newJSON =  encode_json($tempHash);
```

Above code is not working as i expect. 
It is actually adding the key-value pair by creating new element {'Person'}->{'Home'}->{'Laptop'}} instead of adding them under an existing element ( which is expected behavior ).

Can someone point me to correct syntax or any other suggestions is appreciated.

I have tried explaining the question in very simple possible way ( original code have become very complicated now and doing many different stuffs ). let me know if more details are needed or more information is needed for what i research i did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your lines

```
 %filedata = ('Key', 123456789);

 # insert the fileKey now. Think about how to insert the file key here
 push @{ $tempHash->{'Person'}->{'Home'}->{'Laptop'}}, $\%fileData;
```

use lines

```
my ($key, $val) = ('Key', 123456789);
$tempHash->{'Person'}->{'Home'}->{'Laptop'}->{$key} = $val;
```

You can even insert bunch of values into bunch of keys using hash slice.

```
my %filedata = ( Key1 => 123, Key2 => 456 );
@{ $tempHash->{Person}{Home}{Laptop} }{keys %filedata} = values %filedata;
```

Which is just specialised version of more general but tedious code

```
my @keys   = qw(Key1 Key2);
my @values = (123, 456);
@{ $tempHash->{Person}{Home}{Laptop} }{@keys} = @values;
```

Comment: Thanks this example was very helpful. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to set the key and value directly. The Laptop portion of your JSON is *not* an array, so you can't push elements onto it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;


my $json;
{
   local $/;
   $json = from_json( <DATA> );
}

$json->{Person}->{Home}->{Laptop}->{Key} = 123456789;
print Dumper $json;

__DATA__
{
   "Person": {
      "ID": "0", 
      "SchemaVersion": "1.0.8", 
       "Home": {
          "ID": "ABC-XYZ", 

          "Laptop": {
             "FileName": "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz"
           }, 

          "Location": {
              "Number": "62", 
              "MaxSize": "0", 
              "Comment": { }, 
              "SiteName": { }
           }, 

          "State": "Unknown"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it did worked,  Element "Key" does not already exit so i need to add that as well. This was the reason i tried using hashmap

Comment: Error message when using the way you suggested :  Can't use string ("{ Person":{"ID":"0","T")as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use.

Comment: @user1188611: String is not obviously a hash, you forget decode JSON.

Comment: @user1188611 Assigning a value to a Hash key creates the key if it does not already exist

Answer (score 1):

I would to use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);

my $wantadd->{Person}->{Home}->{Laptop} = {
    key => 123456,
    some => 'data1',
    other => 'data2',
    deeper => {
        deep1 => "deep1",
        deep2 => "deep2",
    },
};

my $json_str = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $json = JSON->new();

my $tempHash = $json->decode($json_str);  
my $newhash = merge($tempHash,$wantadd);
print $json->pretty->encode($newhash);

#or in compact form
print encode_json(merge(decode_json($json_str),$wantadd));

__DATA__
{
   "Person" : {
      "ID" : "0",
      "SchemaVersion" : "1.0.8",
      "Home" : {
         "State" : "Unknown",
         "Laptop" : {
            "FileName" : "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz"
         },
         "Location" : {
            "MaxSize" : "0",
            "Comment" : {},
            "SiteName" : {},
            "Number" : "62"
         },
         "ID" : "ABC-XYZ"
      }
   }
}
```

it prints:

```
{
   "Person" : {
      "ID" : "0",
      "Home" : {
         "ID" : "ABC-XYZ",
         "Location" : {
            "MaxSize" : "0",
            "SiteName" : {},
            "Number" : "62",
            "Comment" : {}
         },
         "State" : "Unknown",
         "Laptop" : {
            "FileName" : "/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz",
            "key" : 123456,
            "other" : "data2",
            "deeper" : {
               "deep1" : "deep1",
               "deep2" : "deep2"
            },
            "some" : "data1"
         }
      },
      "SchemaVersion" : "1.0.8"
   }
}

{"Person":{"SchemaVersion":"1.0.8","Home":{"ID":"ABC-XYZ","Laptop":{"key":123456,"FileName":"/usr/temp/RPM_020515_.tar.gz","some":"data1","deeper":{"deep1":"deep1","deep2":"deep2"},"other":"data2"},"State":"Unknown","Location":{"MaxSize":"0","SiteName":{},"Number":"62","Comment":{}}},"ID":"0"}}
```

added the new data into the desired location.

Comment: actually i am using perl v5.10.0, so this solution will not work for that version. I just tried doing this and it failed. Compatibility/version issue.

Comment: this is stupid of using such an old version but i am restricted to use that old version, Any other suggestions?

Comment: yes i am having "Use strict" only in my perl script. But i get following message when i use above solution "Can't locate Clone.pm in @INC ..." and it fails without producing any output

Comment: yes, it uses the module [Hash::Merge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge) what needs [Clone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Clone).

Comment: yes so is there any other way of doing same solution which odes not have dependency on clone?

Comment: Probably others will suggest you an another solution.